# .setAdapter(adapter); Giving an NullPointerException

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make adapters for spinners, however I get an NullPointerException on answertime.setAdapter(adapter); Why is this? My arrays are in the strings.xml where they should be?
Here is the full code.

```
package lijap.app.starcraft2counters;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner answertime;
Spinner gametime;
Spinner missesallowed;

String[] answerseconds = { "Unlimited", "1 second", "2 seconds",
        "3 seconds", "4 seconds", "5 seconds" };

String[] gameminutes = { "Unlimited", "1 minute", "2 minutes", "3 minutes",
        "4 minutes", "5 minutes" };

String[] numberofmisses = { "Unlimited", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.AnswerSeconds, R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
    answertime.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.GameMinutes, R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
    gametime.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.NumberOfMisses, R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
    missesallowed.setAdapter(adapter);


    answertime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_answertime);
    answertime.setAdapter(adapter);
    answertime.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    missesallowed = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_mistakenumber);
    missesallowed.setAdapter(adapter2);
    missesallowed.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    gametime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_gametime);
    gametime.setAdapter(adapter3);
    gametime.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Any help is appreciated- Lijap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never initialize `answertime`, `gametime`, or `missesallowed`. you need to do something like this,

```
answertime = findViewById(R.id.<the id for this spinner>);
gametime = findViewById(R.id.<the id for this spinner>);
missesallowed = findViewById(R.id.<the id for this spinner>);
```

before you call `setAdapter()` on them.

also, here's another problem,

```
ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.GameMinutes, R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
gametime.setAdapter(adapter);
```

notice that you construct something into the reference `adapter2`, then you modify `adapter`, and set `adapter` as the adapter for the spinner. is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize

```
Spinner answertime;
Spinner gametime;
Spinner missesallowed;
```

Otherwise, the following line will give you a `NullPointerException`:

```
answertime.setAdapter(adapter);
gametime.setAdapter(adapter);
missesallowed.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To initialize the `Spinner`s, you should add something like this after you call `setContentView`:

```
answertime = findViewById(R.id.answertime);
gametime = findViewById(R.id.gametime);
missesallowed = findViewById(R.id.missesallowed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the view visibility is set to View.VISIBLE